# Slow speed due to multiple useless devices in wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a wifi router with 2.4 and 5 Ghz band, My main devices like Mobile and laptop are connected on 5Ghz and some like Wii Lights, AC's, Alexa etc are connected on 2.4Ghz band. When all lights etc are connected (30 devices) they make the speed very slow for normal browsing. Are there any settings that I can change in router to increase performance on my 5Ghz band for main devices and maybe decrease for extra devices. These just need to stay connected and not much are used. I already changed the mode to 802.11-b of 2.4 channel any other thing that might help would be good.

Comment: Without knowing your router it is very hard to know your options - and the bottleneck may be elsewhere. Putting the iot devices on a different AP might be a good idea, both performance and security wise.

Comment: Sir, this is the router info, https://ibb.co/vk3krSP, I have connected the it devices on the different band, isn't it the different AP, if not I'll see that, also when i used only the normal devices 2-3 months back and no IOT ones on same network and router everything was fine

Comment: I do mean literally a separate access point or router (set up to be an access point) handling just those devices

Comment: Okk Got it, but it would be difficult for me to get a new router currently, any settings in the current one to improve the situation would be very helpful.

Comment: I'd be very worried if only 30 smart devices are impacting browsing speed - soundslike some of them are "calling home" (probably china) a little too much

Answer (score 1):

Many routers are able to create a "Guest WLAN" in addition to the main WLAN - you should connect your IoT devices to this guest WLAN, which also disallows them to access your computers, NAS etc.

Not all routers are created equally smart, but in the better ones the traffic from the main WLAN is priorized ober the guest traffic.